# What do I have to add to my build.sbt in order to work with halbuilder?

Tags: scala, sbt, hal

I can't find how to use halbuilder in my spray project. The first step is to add the correct dependencies to my build.sbt file and then I can read the API documentation.

Anyone out there has used halbuilder in a scala project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
libraryDependencies += "com.theoryinpractise" % "halbuilder-core" % "2.0.1"
```

From [googled example](https://bitbucket.org/loyolachicagocs_distributed/sensorproxy-scalatra-scala/commits/01ea63e83f44b5ee1a26aebffd5f85ef2dfd56ff#side-by-side-3-content).

It seems it works:

```
scala> import com.theoryinpractise.halbuilder._
import com.theoryinpractise.halbuilder._
```

It's a correct location according to [pom.xml](https://github.com/HalBuilder/halbuilder-scala/blob/develop/pom.xml):

```
<groupId>com.theoryinpractise</groupId>
<artifactId>halbuilder-scala</artifactId>
```

*Disclaimer: I've never used it.*